# What's the right position of each of the armors in the chateau?

Tags: uncharted-3

I'm playing *Uncharted 3* and in the chateau at some point you have to rotate all the armor to open some hidden door.

The game directs you to Drake's diary which has the following image:

[image]

I tried rotating them so they all face each other, so they all look away from each other, but I think I'm missing some detail.

**So how must I rotate the armors to continue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this walkthough](http://www.rarityguide.com/articles/articles/960/1/Uncharted-3-Walkthrough-Chapter-6---The-Chateau/Page1.html):

> Observe the statues and the fireplace. This is a puzzle. Lawrence made a note about something like this. Press select to open Nate's Journal. Four knights, with an axe, a shield, a sword, and a morning star. Just like the ones in this room.
>
> You've got to turn each knight so it's facing the right way. Adjust the knights' position to match the the direction they are facing in the journal. The suit of armor thats holding the shield should face the one holding an axe. The knight holding the axe should face the knight with the shield, and the same for the one holding the mace. The knight holding the sword should face the knight holding the axe.

Comment: That worked, nice work :D